# Safari (6) and HTTPS

Tags: safari, http

Is there any method to make Safari (6) trying to connect to a website with HTTPS connection and switch to HTTP if HTTPS is not supported?

(See HTTPS Everywhere for Firefox).

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment. According to the HTTPS Everywhere FAQ:

> Q. Will there be a version of HTTPS Everywhere for IE, Safari, Opera, or some other browser?
>
> A. Some members of our developer community are working on an IE port of HTTPS Everywhere. As of early 2012, the Safari extension API does not offer a way to perform secure rewriting of http requests to https.

Source: https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/faq

Comment: Even HTTPS everywhere doesn't automatically try HTTPS for every website. See the FAQ "Why use a whitelist of sites that support HTTPS? Why can't you try to use HTTPS for every last site, and only fall back to HTTP if it isn't available?"

Answer (score 0):

One way to get functionality similar to HTTPS Everywhere for Safari is to use [Glimmerblocker](http://glimmerblocker.org/) which acts as a filtering proxy. Most filter rules are focused on blocking ads, but there is also a set of files which can [SSLify sites](http://glimmerblocker.org/wiki/Filters).

Answer (score 0):

There is https://www.sslenforcer.com, which does the same thing for all Apps.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer.